# Set new column as first column of table

Tags: database-migration, phinx

I'd like to use the MysqlAdapter::FIRST constant of phinx to set a new column as first column in a new table.
The migration does run through, but does not set the desired column as first column.

I already checked the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/migrations.html#adding-a-column-after-another-column) and had a look at the [unittest](https://github.com/cakephp/phinx/blob/b2eef811863e6c4e96bac0136263f502424a170f/tests/Phinx/Db/Adapter/MysqlAdapterTest.php#L764) on Github.

The `$this->table` method does not allow a third value, which leads me to this code below:

```php
$table = $this->table('acbase', ['id' => 'idAcBase']);  
        $table->addColumn('acbase_TS', 'timestamp', ['default' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'update'=> 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'after' => \Phinx\Db\Adapter\MysqlAdapter::FIRST])
            ->create();
```